# ¿Atributo para validar distintos Enum?

Tags: c#, validación, enum, dataannotations

Quisiera crear un attribute para validar si los valores de un Enum cualquiera son válidos o no, y poder utilizar ese mismo attribute para cualquier tipo de Enum que haya creado.

Digamos que tengo esta clase la cual contiene dos Enums distintos:

```
public class MyClass{

  [ValidateEnum(inputEnum = MyEnum1)]
  public MyEnum1 myEnum1 {get;set;}

  [ValidateEnum(inputEnum = MyEnum2)]
  public MyEnum1 myEnum1 {get;set;}
}

public enum MyEnum1
{
    myEnum1Value1 = 1,
    myEnum1Value2= 2
}

public enum MyEnum2
{
    myEnum2Value1 = 6,
    myEnum2Value2= 8
}
```

Lo que quisiera ahora es pasar el Enum como parámetro o de alguna forma poderlo castear (Desde un string?) para poder hacer una validación más o menos así:

```
public class ValidateEnum : ValidationAttribute
{
    public Enum inputEnum { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(inputEnum), value))
           return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

El problema es que cuando intento pasar el Enum como parámetro desde la clase ([ValidateEnum(inputEnum = MyEnum)]), Visual Studio (V2022) me arroja "*Error CS0655  'MyEnum' no es un argumento de atributo con nombre válido porque no es un tipo de parámetro de atributo válido*", es decir, no se puede pasar el Enum tal cuál como un parámetro.

¿Alguna idea de cómo solucionar esto? No quiero tener que crear un attribute por cada Enum que quiera validar.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: no entiendo tu escenario, no se que queres validar de un enum, ya que un enum es una enumeracion que solo se usa para tener una lista "valida" de nombres de tipos con valores predefinidos... no deberias recibir de ningun lado el enum, salvo que lo uses como si fuera el valor de una tabla dentro de un combo, y entonces el usuario no podria poner un valor invalido... Si podes recibir como parametro un enum, no entiendo como lo queres usar ahi...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es algo muy parecido a lo planteado por Yussef, con algunas modificaciones para mi caso particular.

Ya que no es posible enviar el Enum como parámetro *per se*, la solución pasa por enviar simplemente el ***tipo del Enum*** como parámetro en el atributo

```
[ValidateEnum(ErrorMessage = "Custom ErrorMessage", MyEnum = typeof(CustomEnum) )]
    public CustomEnum? customEnum { get; set; }
```

Es decir, la clave está en "MyEnum = **typeof(** CustomEnum **)**". Y en la validación ya se puede usar el *Enum.IsDefined* más o menos como lo planteó Yussef, solamente que no se obtiene el tipo del valor que se ingresa como un input (value.GetType() ), sino que se usa directamente el tipo del Enum que le estamos enviando como parámetro del atributo

```
public class ValidateEnum : ValidationAttribute
{

    public Type MyEnum { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null || (int) value == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Enum.IsDefined(this.MyEnum, (int)value))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

En mi caso ha funcionado muy bien para cualquier valor no válido de un Enum en particular que esté utilizando en ese momento.

Answer (score 1):

Podría ser algo como esto:

```
        public override bool IsValid(object? value)
        {
            if (value == null || !Enum.IsDefined(value.GetType(), value))
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

```
        [ValidateEnum]
        public MyEnum1 myEnum1 { get; set; }
```

Ahora esta validación así como está yo no le veo mucho sentido. En mi experiencia (quizás tú tienes un caso que desconozco) uno utiliza este tipo de validación cuando viene el dato desde un POST por ejemplo, ahí el controlador transforma lo enviado (por ejemplo un JSON) en un objeto de C#. Esto sucede antes de la validación. Por lo que si tu envías por ejemplo:

```
{
    "myEnum1" : 9999
}
```

Eso no lo va a validar, porque al castearlo no lo va a poder hacer, ya que, 9999 no es valor valido de la enumeración. O sea da error antes que entre a isValid